# Make alert appear when start typing input

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am trying to make something happen only when a user inputs data into an input element that has been created. However I don't want to validate that data has been inputted or make the user press a button to check if data has been inputted, I want something to happen as soon as the first data value is typed in the input field. I decide to just use a demo of something similar that I want to create - to cut out the clutter:

I have tried:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");

if(input == ""){
alert("no value");
}else{
input.style.background = "blue";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

But nothing seems to be working. For what reason is it not working?
So in this example I would only want the background to be blue when the first data value is typed in.
 I also tried:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");

if(input.length == 0){
alert("no value");
}else{
input.style.background = "blue";
}
```

and:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");


if(input == undefined){
alert("no value");
}else{
input.style.background = "blue";
}
```

as well as variations using `!=` and `!==`

Is it something small I'm missing?

Comment: `input` in your example is the whole DOM element, not the value. Get this with `input.value` then compare the length of that. On top of that you need to fire this on input being typed, attach a change or keyup event listener to your input element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener https://jsfiddle.net/nzoeywg0/1/

Comment: `var input = document.getElementById("input"); input.addEventListener("input",function(e) { do something here with this.value })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were checking the actual element, not it's value. And, you didn't have any event listener set up for the element. But, it doesn't make much logical sense to check for no value after a value has been entered.

```js
// When data is inputted into the element, trigger a callback function
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("input", function(){
  // Check the value of the element
  if(input.value == ""){
    alert("no value");
  }else{
    input.style.background = "blue";
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Comment: @mplungjan No, it's not. That's not what I interpreted the OP to be asking for.

Comment: @mplungjan *However I don't want to validate that data has been inputted* <-- The OPs requirements seem to conflict so I was a little confused.

Comment: Backspace or cut would alert

Comment: @mplungjan Could be. Upon reading it for the 5th time, it seems like he wants to differentiate between the field having data or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
**jQuery**

```
$('#input').keyup(()=>{
  if($('#input').val() == ""){
    alert("no value");
  } else{
    $('#input').css({backgroundColor: 'your-color'});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function handleCurrentInput(event) {
  const value = event.target.value;
  if (!value) {
    alert("no value");
  } else {
    alert("value entered -->", value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" onInput="handleCurrentInput(event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try this

```
    <input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="inputfun()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function inputfun(){
            var input = document.getElementById("input");

            if(input.value == ""){
            input.style.background = "";
            alert("no value");
            }else{
            input.style.background = "blue";
            }
        }
    </script>
```